# Prestashop hiding category description because of pagination

Tags: php, pagination, prestashop, categories, prestashop-1.7

I've noticed something weird about our prestashop store - the category description that's displayed on page 1 disappears when the customer switches to any other page.
https://vipkoszulka.pl/91-pielegniarka
https://vipkoszulka.pl/91-pielegniarka?page=2
(below the products, above the footer. the div contains category title as well)

Furthermore, if you go from page 1 to any other page and then back to page 1, the category description is gone as well. The div that's supposed to contain all the info (#js-product-list-bottom) is just empty.

Can someone point me out which controller is responsible for this? I found part of the script that's responsible for pagination in ProductListingFrontController.php:

```
        ProductSearchQuery $query,
        ProductSearchResult $result
    ) {
        $pagination = new Pagination();
        $pagination
            ->setPage($query->getPage())
            ->setPagesCount(
                (int) ceil($result->getTotalProductsCount() / $query->getResultsPerPage())
            )
        ;

        $totalItems = $result->getTotalProductsCount();
        $itemsShownFrom = ($query->getResultsPerPage() * ($query->getPage() - 1)) + 1;
        $itemsShownTo = $query->getResultsPerPage() * $query->getPage();

        $pages = array_map(function ($link) {
            $link['url'] = $this->updateQueryString(array(
                'page' => $link['page'] > 1 ? $link['page'] : null,
            ));

            return $link;
        }, $pagination->buildLinks());

        //Filter next/previous link on first/last page
        $pages = array_filter($pages, function ($page) use ($pagination) {
            if ('previous' === $page['type'] && 1 === $pagination->getPage()) {
                return false;
            }
            if ('next' === $page['type'] && $pagination->getPagesCount() === $pagination->getPage()) {
                return false;
            }

            return true;
        });

        return array(
            'total_items' => $totalItems,
            'items_shown_from' => $itemsShownFrom,
            'items_shown_to' => ($itemsShownTo <= $totalItems) ? $itemsShownTo : $totalItems,
            'current_page' => $pagination->getPage(),
            'pages_count' => $pagination->getPagesCount(),
            'pages' => $pages,
            // Compare to 3 because there are the next and previous links
            'should_be_displayed' => (count($pagination->buildLinks()) > 3),
        );
    }
```

But it only deals with products, not the description itself.

Answer (score 0):

This is not really an issue. As long as you don't have a description on the second page, it's ok from the SEO perspective. The most important is to have a description available on the first page when you visit the page directly.